# $g\circ f$ is Surjective and $g$ is Injective then Prove that $f$ is surjective

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, proof-verification

Let $f : A \to B$ and $g : B \to C$ be functions such that $g\circ f: A \to C$ is a surjection and $g$ is an injection , Then prove that $f$ is a surjection.

Since $g$ is a function $\forall y \in B$ we have $$g(y)=z \tag{1}$$ for some $z \in C$

Since $g\circ f$ is a surjection $\forall z \in C \exists x \in A$ such that $$g\circ f(x)=z$$ that is

$$g(f(x))=z \tag{2}$$

from $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have

$$g(y)=g(f(x))$$ and since $g$ is an injection we get

$$f(x)=y$$ so $f$ is surjective.

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct. Still, being explicit about $g$ "being a function" (in order to obtain (1)) is a bit pedantic. These things are generally silently understood to be so, no need to make them explicit.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not correct, sorry. The fact that you list as $(1)$ is obvious and there's no connection between $z$ in $(1)$ and $z$ in $(2)$: the former is under the scope of an existential quantifier, the latter of a universal quantifier.

---

> Start with $y$ in $B$ and prove there exists $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Set $z=g(y)$. Then, since $g\circ f$ is surjective, there exists $x\in A$ such that $z=g\circ f(x)$. Therefore
$$
g(f(x))=g(y)
$$
and, since $g$ is injective, we can conclude $f(x)=y$.